# Contact multiple variable with string bash

Tags: bash, shell

This is my script code

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp=$(date +%F-%T)
clinet_id="123"

STRING=s3://<bucketname>/folder/$client_id/$client_id_gdpr_access_report_$timestamp.csv
echo "$STRING"
$SHELL
```

If i run this code am getting timestamp value.csv file
how can i concatenate  variable with string.
am expecting out put like below

```
s3://<bucketname>/folder/123/123_report_2022-01-25-14:55:47.csv
```

i can able to concatenate`access_report_$timestamp.csv`
if i add $client_id_ in the beginning, it will print

```
 2022-01-25-14:55:47.csv
```

Expecting a better advice

Comment: `If i run this code am getting timestamp value.csv` Doesn't the code print an error message upon execution?

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out several errors with how you're defining and using variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look better at the names of your variables; it's 'client_id' not 'clinet_id' ...

And you should take care of double quoting your string, and put braces around variables when in doubt:

```
STRING="s3://<bucketname>/folder/${client_id}/${client_id}_gdpr_access_report_${timestamp}.csv"
```